# search results not returning to original form menu

Tags: database

I have the following code in access to conduct a search in the records on a field "ClockNo". It works, but when the answer does not bring in a match, the form goes to a blank page and the user has to exit the form. I would like if the clock number was not found it to go back to the original form and send a message the number was not found.

I normally use the wizard commands and do not work a lot with the VBA coding. I tried to add a Then DooCmd.Openform, but I must not be applying it correctly or it is the wrong way to go.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Private Sub SearchClockNoBtn_Click()

```
Dim S As String
If IsNull(ClockNo) Then Exit Sub
                            
S = InputBox("Please enter Clock Number", "Clock Number", ClockNo)
If S = "" Then Exit Sub
    
Me.Filter = "ClockNo LIKE ""*" & S & "*"""
Me.FilterOn = True
```

End Sub

Regards,
Charlene

Tried Then DoCmd.OpenForm to return to the original form "EmployeeLOCKEDF"
It still opened a blank page.